# Is it okay to ignore conflicting constraints in Xcode?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am working on an app in Xcode and I get a lot of conflicting constraints when I run it in the simulator even though everything looks just fine. I've tried to solve every conflict but often ends up screwing up everything.

Someone told me that it's okay to ignore them as long as it doesn't affect the app from working. But is it true that I can just ignore it? Will App Store allow me to publish app with tons of conflicting constrains?

Comment: Always resolve the conflicting constraints. Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not okay. It is not specified how the layout engine resolves conflicts (it lists conflicts that it decided to ignore in a particular case in the end of the log message). So even if it works now, on your device with your OS version, there is no guarantee, that it won't brake in future/on some other device. It will most likely work, but there is no guarantee, so it's not safe.

The AppStore review team will allow your app to the AppStore though. If they won't encounter some terrible UI-related bugs due to broken constraints working differently on their side, I mean.

Comment: Wish someone would have told me this earlier, guess I'm gonna spend some time to figure out how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: @aaa912009, you're welcome :) Just resolve those conflicts one by one. Hint: sometimes it is easier to rewrite the constraints on a given view from scratch. Another hint: take a look at the constraint that the layout engine ignores (in the log message). If it works just as it should without it, do you really need it? Also, if you see `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint ` in the log message, you most likely forgot to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` to `NO` \ `false` on some of your views. Good luck! :)